# How to get nested JSON / hash elements using postgres_ext-serializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I'm trying to get the postgres_ext-serializers gem working, and I built a test project very similar to https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext-serializers/blob/master/test/test_helper.rb

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :mobile
  embed :ids, include: true
  has_one :address, serializer: AddressSerializer

  def include_mobile?
    false
  end
  alias_method :include_address?, :include_mobile?
end

class AddressSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :district_name
  embed :ids, include: true
end
```

When I try to run the serializers the output doesn't seem to have nested elements. For example my serializer to_json output is:

"{\"users\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Aaron\",\"mobile\":null}, \n {\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Bob\",\"mobile\":null}],\"addresses\":[{\"id\":1,\"district_name\":\"Rob's Address\"}]}"

Notice how users and address are two separate elements of a hash, intead of being nested. If I remove the postgres_ext-serializers gem, then the output is as expected:

"[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Rob\",\"mobile\":null,\"address\":{\"id\":1,\"district_name\":\"Rob's Address\"}},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Bob\",\"mobile\":null,\"address\":null}]"

The address is embedded in the user hash exactly how I'm expecting it.

What am I missing, do I need to change anything to make the elements nested when using postgres_ext-serializers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that the JSON you receive after serialization is what `postgres_ext-serializers` expects. Take a look into [this test](https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext-serializers/blob/master/test/sideloading_test.rb#L153-L165). `expected_json` in the first test case case is:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": <UserID>,
      "name": "John",
      "mobile": "51111111",
      "offer_ids": [],
      "reviewed_offer_ids": []
    }
  ],
  "offers": [],
  "addresses": [
    {
      "id": <AddressID>,
      "district_name": "mumbai"
    }
  ]
}
```

It looks very similar to the JSON you have received. But, to be honest, as `include_address?` method in your example returns `false`, I expect you must have not `"addresses"` field included into resulting JSON at all.

Comment: Yes, that's interesting... do you think that the output is formatted like that due to limitations of the postgres json functionality, or is this a preferred json output as I guess it technically saves duplication? All the apis that I've seen generally have full nested objects and not just IDs referencing top level objects?

Comment: I have `postgres_ext-serializers`'s code reviewed and, seems, it has no special case for the `has_one` relation, unlike `has_many` and `belongs_to`. It looks like inconsistency with `active_model_serializers` gem, open an issue on GitHub and see, what the creator thinks about it. Currently, I suggest you to add `user_id` field to attributes list in the `AddressSerializer`. At least, you will be able to restore relations between `User` and `Address` models from resulting JSON.